# Filtering a file by specific elements in mandatory order

Tags: awk, filter, range

I am trying to filter a file by its `index` column and make sure that I am left with some numbers. The `index` column is normally having any number from `0 to 10` in the original file (`file1.txt`).

The example file is (with dashes inside separating each chunk from each other):

```
file1.txt
index age_1  age_2
    0  44      34
    1  10      12
    1  34      44
    2   1      -3
    3   4     -10.3
    3   3.390   4
    4  43       3
    --
    1 -90.3     2
    2  32       3
    3  43     -20
    4   2       2
    --
    0  34      34
    2  21      12
    4  -0.9    12
    --
    4  -2.19   34
    4   4       4
    5   5       -1
    6   4      12
    --
    3  -12      3
```

I am trying to filter the each chunk in between dashes separately, and keep the chunks which have the range in their `index` column from `1 to 4` with each element `(1,2,3,4)` at least once present.
So the expected output would look like:

```
index age_1  age_2
    1  10      12
    1  34      44
    2   1      -3
    3   4     -10.3
    3   3.390   4
    4  43       3
    --
    1 -90.3     2
    2  32       3
    3  43     -20
    4   2       2
```

My current trial is just able to check for the range in the `index` column, but I could not specify a mandatory filtering:

```
cat file1.txt | awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=$1' | tail -n +2 | awk '$1>=1 && $1<=4'
1   10  12
1   34  44
2   1   -3
3   4   -10.3
3   3.390   4
4   43  3
1   -90.3   2
2   32  3
3   43  -20
4   2   2
2   21  12
4   -0.9    12
4   -2.19   34
4   4   4
3   -12 3
```

I lose the chunks and all the output is mixed without specific filtering. It just can print any number in between 1 to 4.

How can introduce a strict filtering for numbers present in the specific column by keeping each chunk separate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine whether a chunk's first column contains all numbers in the selected range you can index first column elements in an array while processing the chunk and compare its length to size of the range at the end as done in below script.

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == 1 {
  print
  next
}
$1 == "--" {
  if (length(arr) == 4) {
    printf "%s%s", sep, buf
  }
  sep = ($0 ORS)
  buf = ""
  delete arr
}
$1 >= 1 && $1 <= 4 {
  buf = (buf $0 ORS)
  arr[$1]
}
END {
  if (length(arr) == 4) {
    printf "%s%s", sep, buf
  }
}
```

It yields:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
index age_1  age_2
    1  10      12
    1  34      44
    2   1      -3
    3   4     -10.3
    3   3.390   4
    4  43       3
    --
    1 -90.3     2
    2  32       3
    3  43     -20
    4   2       2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have an error with this solution: "fatal: attempt to use scalar `arr' as an array " So, what does arr refer to in here?

Answer (score 3):

This is just a slightly different way to write the solution that [@oguzismail already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61042419/1745001). We came up with the same approach but he posted first. I upvoted his and was going to delete mine but eventually decided to leave it here just as an alternative way to implement the same approach (the main difference is my use of a function to contain the printing code) in case anyone's interested but he was first so he should get the votes.

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 { print; next }
($1 >= 1) && ($1 <= 4) {
    rec = rec $0 ORS
    hits[$1]
}
$1 == "--" {
    rec = rec $0 ORS
    prt()
}
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( length(hits) == 4 ) {
        printf "%s", rec
    }
    rec = ""
    delete hits
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
index age_1  age_2
    1  10      12
    1  34      44
    2   1      -3
    3   4     -10.3
    3   3.390   4
    4  43       3
    --
    1 -90.3     2
    2  32       3
    3  43     -20
    4   2       2
    --
```

Comment: I was gonna say *wouldn't it be better if you'd `split("1 2 3 4",arr)` and `delete arr[$1]` for each record? then you'd just do `! length(arr)` and print the chunk.*, but then you deleted. Upvoted back btw

Comment: Yeah, I went through a couple of iterations including one where I thought the OP wanted $1s in a list rather than a range and that was when I was using a split().